# Opening SoundCloud from a deep link opens to the Stream tab instead of the Home tab

Tags: ios, soundcloud

Currently, if you try to open `soundcloud://`, it opens the app, then redirects to Stream tab. However, if you simply launch the app yourself, it will open on the Home tab.

Is there any reason to it, and can I redirect to Home tab instead if linking from other app?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is there any reason to it?

Yes, SoundCloud built their universal links this way.  The base URL scheme (`soundcloud://`) takes you to the Stream tab, because that's what they want.

I've tried experimenting with a few other paths, but it does not look like there are any that take you to the "Home" tab.

As a workaround, any unsupported deep link (such as `soundcloud://home` will take the user to the "Home" tab, but an error alert will be displayed.  Another workaround would be to take the user to the "Authentication" page (`soundcloud://page/authentication`), which will present the login view over the "Home" tab.  This is what SoundCloud does on their mobile site.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer.